# YII framework _form.php with different contents

Tags: view, yii

Is it possible to use same _form.php in two different view files with different content in yii framework? If yes then how to achieve it.

Comment: In login.php I used partial view of _form.php if I wish to use same _form.php in register.php view, Is it possible?

Comment: You can find an example of this in `create.php` and `update.php` which both include `_form.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it however both models have to have the same attributes.

in views/pleace1/create.php and update.php

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('/pleace1/_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

in views/pleace2/create.php and update.php

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('/pleace1/_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

in views/pleace1/_form.php change form widget start to:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'stl-' . $this->controller_alias . '-form',
```

in both controllers where you using form set public controller_alias to model name without prefix (if you use it)

Comment: the clue is '/pleace1/_form' in both renderPartial functions